# Next13 'Cannot access 'slice' before initialization' when using createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux, redux-thunk, next.js13

I want to fetch some user data from the backend directly into redux and for that, I used `createAsyncThunk`. I've created the `slice` and I made a `getUserData` function inside the `slice file using` createAsyncThunk`and added the`extraReducers`.

The issue is that I need to `dispatch` the function and I want to dispatch it after I get the `token` from the backend because I need to send the `token` back to get the user backend. But if I call the dispatch of `getUserData()` inside the login function when I run `npm run build` I get this error

An Error occurred prerendering page "/login". Read more:

```
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'slice' before initialization
```

My file structure looks like this:

[image]

The store is outside of the `src` directory.

I tried to dispatch `getUserData()` in other files. If I dispatch it inside the main page from the app I get this error when I run `npm run build`.

```
Collecting page data .ReferenceError: Cannot access 'user_slice' before initialization
```

I should mention that I do not use this file yet. I have set up in `next.config.ts` a redirect from '/' to a different page.

If I dispatch it inside the main `layout`, or any other layouts I get this error directly into the browser.

```
Error: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization
src\store\createStore.ts (33:11) @ userSlice

  31 | authSlice,
  32 | modalSlice,
> 33 | userSlice,
     |         ^
  34 | currencySlice,
  35 | });
  36 |
```

But if I dispatch the function inside the shop page works fine... but, it doesn't make sense to dispatch the function there.

I have even created a `codesandbox` and I added all the files. I've also deleted a lot of things to manage to make the app work inside the `codesandbox` and some sensitive code. The funny thing is that inside the `codesandbox` the build works fine... Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sad-artem-dqgjmq) (If the app doesn't run for you please go to terminal user `ctrl + c` and the `npm run dev`).

I have no idea why it works fine inside the shop page but not on the login page and also why it worked inside the codesandbox. Can someone please help?

Store code:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import createWebStorage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage/createWebStorage';

import authSlice from './auth/slice';
import modalSlice from './modal/slice';
import userSlice from './user/slice';
import currencySlice from './currency/slice';

const createNoopStorage = () => {
  return {
    getItem(_key: any) {
      return Promise.resolve(null);
    },
    setItem(_key: any, value: any) {
      return Promise.resolve(value);
    },
    removeItem(_key: any) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    },
  };
};

const storage =
  typeof window !== 'undefined'
    ? createWebStorage('local')
    : createNoopStorage();

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authSlice,
  modalSlice,
  userSlice,
  currencySlice,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['authSlice', 'userSlice'],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppDispatch = ReturnType<typeof store.dispatch>;
```

The Slice code:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { initialState } from './initialsState';
import { get } from '@/helpers/utils/fetch';

export const getUserData = createAsyncThunk('user/userData', async () => {
  try {
    return await get({ url: '/api/user' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('thunk user data error: ', error);
  }
});

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    clearUserData: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getUserData.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(getUserData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'success';
        state.user = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getUserData.rejected, (state, action) => {
        (state.status = 'failed'), (state.error = action.error.message);
      });
  },
});

export const { clearUserData } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

The login function

```
  const onLogin = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.post('/api/auth/login', userData);
      const token = response.data.accessTokens;

      dispatch(setToken(token));
      (dispatch as ThunkDispatch<RootState, void, AnyAction>)(getUserData());

      push(routes.shop);
      setError('');
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error: any) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 400) {
        setError('Incorrect credentials');
      } else {
        console.log('Login Error', error);
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell it looks like your `getUserData` action is trying to close over and use the `store` prior to the `store` being instantiated. The file that creates the `store` object is importing from the file that creates the slice.

Instead of importing the `store`, the `getUserData` action should use the second argument that is passed to the [payload creator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator), e.g. the `thunkAPI` object.

Example:

```js
export const getUserData = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/userData',
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const userToken = userTokenSelector(thunkApi.getState());

      if (userToken) {
        console.log(userToken);
        return await get({ url: '/api/user' });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('thunk user data error: ', error);
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment but unfortunately I still get the same error :(

Comment: @Oliver Is it possible you have the same, or similar, issue elsewhere where you've effectively created a dependency cycle between files? Think you could create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I have created a codesanbox and I added all the files. of course, I've deleted some stuff that would give errors just because I can't add the entire project. The problem is that the build works in codesandbox xd... https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sad-artem-dqgjmq?file=/src/app/(pages)/shop/page.tsx:14,1

Comment: @Oliver That sandbox appears to get stuck in a render loop for me, upon starting.

Comment: should be fixed now

Comment: @Oliver I'm not sure what the problem is. The sandbox loads, but the app/page never loads.